# Adding Rails tests to an app with datatables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, datatables, minitest, jquery-datatables-rails

I have a Rails app with datatables:

- https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails
- https://github.com/antillas21/ajax-datatables-rails

I am going back and adding some tests (minitest) to my app and I wanted to add some basic tests to confirm that my data tables load properly.

This is a bit beyond my skill level and can't seem to find anything close to this to even try and figure this out on my own.